# Render a web page on top of a video using FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to display some text and images with a specific animation at the beginning of a video using FFMpeg.

Display animated text/images using web langages (HTML+CSS+JS) is pretty easy, but I don't really know if import it into a video with FFMpeg.

What I know is that I can use [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) to render local pages.

Do you know if what I want to do is possible with FFMpeg?

How would you do this otherwise?

Comment: your question is a bit baffling but anyhow..   Windows Movie Maker  or ffmpeg, can turn images into a video.  What you then do with that video e.g. if you put it on a webpage or whatever, is another matter.

Comment: You can always render either local pages if it's just opening a webpage locally. Or, render page(s) local to the web server that your webpage is on(as all websites do as rendered in web browsers).    I haven't tried The CEF thing you link, but it seems like it might be for if you have a program yourself and that program wants to show a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

> Displaying animated text/images using web langages (HTML+CSS+JS) is pretty easy, but I don't know if you can import these into a video with FFMpeg.

To the best of my knowledge, FFmpeg has no ability to interpret HTML/JavaScript itself. However, if you render your web animation as individual still frames or a video, then FFmpeg should be able to work with it natively.

> I would like to display some text and images with a specific animation at the beginning of a video using FFMpeg. [...] What I know is that I can use CEF to render local pages.

Unfortunately, your intent is unclear to me...

- If you wish to simply combine an animation and a video into a final composite video, what I said above applies. CEF seems like it certainly could work in this capacity (as part of a pipeline to render web animation frames/video), though for practical purposes, I am not sure it would be any better than PhantomJS or similar.
- If you are trying to combine these in (at least close to) real-time somehow (in an application or web page), this would likely be much more complicated task and, depending on requirements, may or may not be possible. For web pages, at a guess, WebGL might be something to look into in this case.